# how to make download link in yii?

Tags: php, yii

I want to make a download link for files stored in my webapp directory, so when the user click a link the file should be downloaded, here is my code:

```
 $src= Yii::app()->request->baseUrl;
 $url2 = $src."/CVs/resumes/".$m->idJob."-".$m->cv;
 $url = Yii::app()->getRequest()->sendFile( $m->cv , file_get_contents( $url2 ) );
 echo"<tr><td style='border:4px solid;border-color: black;text-align: center;'>".
 CHtml::link($m->fullName, array('submit'=>$url))."</td></tr>";
```

I got an error that there is no such file or directory, where is the wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try removing the third line and changing the last line to `CHtml::link($m->fullName, $url2)."</td></tr>";`

Please, let me know if it works.

Comment: its worked, but if the file can be opened by brower it will be loaded, as if it .php, .html...

Comment: True, if you want to open it in the browser you have to create a page that "prints" the content of the file itself. I think it would be something like: `http://yoursite.com/file/download/file_name.pdf`, and the download action would look for the file and print it using Yii::app()->getRequest()->sendFile. Get it?

Comment: If it closed the deal, you can mark the question as answered.